# React Native - Randomized view (Circle) on the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I am new to react native. I am trying to build a functionality that needs a View (a circle) randomly moving on the screen. Can someone help me where to start with? Thanks in advance.

update: I am now trying to create a draggable component, which should be dragged along the moving circle and while our dragging component is inside the moving circle, there should be a stopwatch which is running and when we remove hand or the draggable component is outside the moving circle the timer should be reset and start from first. I have created the dragging component and the stop watch, but am not able to get the logic of how to combine these.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, Dimensions,TouchableHighlight,Text, StyleSheet, PanResponder, Animated} from 'react-native'
import { Stopwatch } from 'react-native-stopwatch-timer'
let {width:W,height:H} = Dimensions.get("window");
class Draggable extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  showDraggable: true,
  pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
  opacity: new Animated.Value(1)
};
}
componentWillMount() {
this._val = { x:0, y:0 }
this.state.pan.addListener((value) => this._val = value);
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gesture) => true,
    onPanResponderGrant: (e, gesture) => {
      this.state.pan.setOffset({
        x: this._val.x,
        y:this._val.y
      })

      //console.log(this.state.pan);
      this.state.pan.setValue({ x:0, y:0})
    },
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
      null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y }

    ]),
    onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
      this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this._val.x, y: this._val.y});
  }
  });
 }
render() {
return (
  <View>
    {this.renderDraggable()}
  </View>
);
}
renderDraggable() {
const panStyle = {
  transform: this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()
}
if (this.state.showDraggable) {
  return (
      <Animated.View
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[panStyle, styles.circle, styles.dragstyle,{opacity:this.state.opacity}]}
      />
  );
}
}
}

class MovingCircle extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        pos:new Animated.ValueXY
    }
}
_loopAnimation(){
    let des = {x:W*Math.random(), y:Math.random()*H};
    //console.log(this.state.des)
    Animated.timing(this.state.pos, {
        toValue:des,
        duration:4000
    }).start(()=>{
        this._loopAnimation();
    });
}
componentDidMount(){
    this._loopAnimation();
}
render(){
    return <Animated.View style={{
        width:60,height:60,
        borderRadius:30,
        backgroundColor:"#0A8648",
        position:"absolute",
        left:this.state.pos.x,
        top:this.state.pos.y
    }}/>
  }
  }

export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  stopwatchStart: false,
  stopwatchReset: false,
};
this.toggleStopwatch = this.toggleStopwatch.bind(this);
this.resetStopwatch = this.resetStopwatch.bind(this);
}
toggleStopwatch() {
this.setState({stopwatchStart: !this.state.stopwatchStart, stopwatchReset: false});
}
resetStopwatch() {
this.setState({stopwatchStart: false, stopwatchReset: true});
}
getFormattedTime(time) {
this.currentTime = time;
}
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.mainContainer} >
    <MovingCircle />
    <View style={styles.dragContainer}>
      <Draggable />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.stopWatchHeader} >
      <Stopwatch laps msecs start={this.state.stopwatchStart}
        reset={this.state.stopwatchReset}
        getTime={this.getFormattedTime} />
      <View style={styles.startResetHeader} >
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.toggleStopwatch}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{!this.state.stopwatchStart ? "Start" : "Stop"}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.resetStopwatch}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Reset</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </View>
</View>
);
}
}

let CIRCLE_RADIUS = 25;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
mainContainer: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor:"#D7B68A"
},
circle: {
backgroundColor: "#38395E",
width: CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2,
height: CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2,
borderRadius: CIRCLE_RADIUS
},
dragContainer: {
flex: 1,
flexDirection: "row",
height:150,
justifyContent: "flex-start",
alignItems: "flex-end"
},
stopWatchHeader:{
flexDirection:"row",
backgroundColor:"#FFDEAD",
alignItems:"center",
justifyContent:"space-between",
height:66,
padding:8,
borderRadius:4
},
startResetHeader:{
flex:1,
flexDirection:"row",
justifyContent:"space-around"
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is a sample, adjust the animation duration and view size by yourself. have a look at the [official document of Animations](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View,
    Dimensions,
     StyleSheet, Animated} from 'react-native'

let {width:W,height:H} = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class test0123 extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            pos:new Animated.ValueXY
        }
    }

    _loopAnimation(){
        let des = {x:W*Math.random(), y:Math.random()*H};
        Animated.timing(this.state.pos, {
            toValue:des,
            duration:3000
        }).start(()=>{
            this._loopAnimation();
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this._loopAnimation();
    }

    render(){
        return <Animated.View style={{
            width:50,height:50,
            borderRadius:25,
            backgroundColor:"red",
            position:"absolute",
            left:this.state.pos.x,
            top:this.state.pos.y
        }}/>
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @yangguang . This is what I exactly needed.

Comment: hi @yangguang , I am now trying to create a draggable component, which should be dragged along the moving circle and while our dragging component is inside the moving circle, there should be a stopwatch which is running and when we remove hand or the draggable component is outside the moving circle the timer should be reset and start from first. I have created the dragging component and the stop watch, but am not able to get the logic of how to combine these. If you can provide me any insights about it, it will be helpful.

Comment: I have added the code above at my post @yangguang. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `new Animated.ValueXY()` inside the state that you declared.